# Can one instance of a ServiceClient be used in multiple threaded application (MVC)

Tags: servicestack

In my ASP.NET MVC controllers, I want to call a servicestack based service (not hosted in MVC site).  In order to make the code testable, I want to inject this service client into the contoller constructor.

Assuming I have my own class that inherits from JsonServiceClient, can I use a singleton of that service client for all the MVC calls?  This means the client would have to be thread safe.

Either the (Autofac) registration can be a singleton:

```
builder.RegisterType<SomeServiceClient>().SingleInstance();
```

or it has to be per http request:

```
builder.RegisterType<SomeServiceClient>().InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

Found a blog article where another servicestack user seems to use a singleton, but I was not sure:  [Blog Article Showing an Example](http://www.philliphaydon.com/2012/02/service-stack-i-heart-you-my-conversion-from-wcf-to-ss/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each request is generally re-entrant so it's mostly ThreadSafe to use as a Singleton, the one caveat is that it shares the same CookieContainer, whilst the ServiceClients doesn't mutate the CookieContainer Collection itself, the underlying WebRequest would and it's not known whether WebRequest synchronizes access around it - although I've never personally seen any issues with them.

You can disable Cookies being used (i.e. if your client doesn't require a session) with:

```
client.StoreCookies = false;
```

Comment: If using the same service client for async calls, this can pose a problem.  You end up with System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot re-call BeginGetRequestStream/BeginGetResponse while a previous call is still in progress.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.AsyncServiceClient.SendWebRequestAsync[TResponse](String httpMethod, Object request, RequestState`1 requestState, HttpWebRequest webRequest)

Comment: @WayneBrantley do you have an example that repro's this? as a new HttpWebRequest is created on each request.

Comment: In AppHost.Configure, I registered a instance of a custom class that descended from JsonServiceClient.  This calls simply had helper methods and added a RequestFilter to add a request header.  Then I used that same instance from all over my web application.  This resulted in the errors above, so I changed the registration to have a lambda and 'ReuseScope.None'.  The problem never surfaced again so I moved on.  This was service stack 3.x

Comment: @WayneBrantley ok thanks for the info, looks like I'll need to do more testing around this as I'm not sure how a new ServiceClient instance differs from using the same client given each request doesn't re-use the same underlying request instances.